# Why do I never get the latest chatId in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on it and trying to compare `chatId` with `chatUpdate.id`, checking if both are the same.

My problem is in `chatId`.

The first time the `chatId` is equal to `1`.

I select another chat, so the `chatId` is now the same as `2`.

However, the `chatId` displayed in the `console` remains as `1`.

The component displays the correct `chatId` only if I refresh the page with `F5`

```
export function ChatWindowBody({ chatId }) {
  // chatId is useParams which comes from another component
  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io("http://localhost:8000");

    socket.on("chat_update", (chatUpdate) => {
      console.log("updateId", chatUpdate.id);
      console.log("chatId", chatId);
    });

    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);
}
```

My url looks like this the first time
`http://localhost:3000/chat/1`

And it's the same as this the second time
`http://localhost:3000/chat/2`

Comment: Why in your code you are using port 8000 and in the given URL it's 3000 ? is it typo ?

Comment: socket is running on backend, where port is 8000, frontend uses port 3000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument of useEffect is a dependency array, which says when the effect should run. If you want the effect to run whenever the chatId changes you should add it to the dependency array:

```
export function ChatWindowBody({ chatId }) {
  // chatId is useParams which comes from another component
  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io("http://localhost:8000");

    socket.on("chat_update", (chatUpdate) => {
      console.log("updateId", chatUpdate.id);
      console.log("chatId", chatId);
    });

    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, [chatId]);
}
```

Comment: But in this case, can't we just get rid of the useEffect? Since chatId is a props, you don't have to manage manually its update, right ?

Comment: suggestions are appreciated